# php mail sent from a form

Tags: php, email, joomla

Hello I've been making a site now and have to signup form witch sends the form data to my email.

Ive been testing it at my own xampp server where it works just fine (Cant send the email otherwise it works perfectly)

Then ive been testing it at my host UnoEuro where it used to work aswell, and sending the mails. but now my php checking if the required parts are filled isnt working any more.

its used on a joomla site with sourcer plugin for enable php and html tags in the article.

```
    <div id="blivMedlem">
<?php
if (isset($_POST['sent']))
{
if (!empty($_POST['skMedlem']) && empty($_POST['sNavn'])) { $info = "Husk at skrive skolens navn"; }
else if (!empty($_POST['sNavn']) && empty($_POST['skMedlem'])) { $info = "Husk at sætte et flueben ved Skole medlem, eller fjern skolens navn"; }
elseif (empty($_POST['Navn'])) { $info = "Du skal udfylde navn feltet"; }
elseif (empty($_POST['Adresse'])) { $info = "Du skal udfyldte adresse feltet"; }
elseif (empty($_POST['PostOgBy'])) { $info = "Du skal udfylde postnr og by feltet"; }
elseif (empty($_POST['Fodselsdag'])) { $info = "Du skal udfylde fødselsdags feltet"; }
elseif (empty($_POST['Telefon'])) { $info = "Du skal udfylde Telefon feltet"; }
else
{
if (!empty($_POST['akMedlem'])) {
$akMedlem = "ja";
} else {
$akMedlem = "nej";
}
if (!empty($_POST['stMedlem'])) {
$stMedlem = "ja";
} else {
$stMedlem = "nej";
}
if (!empty($_POST['skMedlem'])) {
$skMedlem = "ja, " . $_POST['sNavn'];
} else {
$skMedlem = "nej";
}
$modtager = "ufl@ufl-ligevaerd.dk";;
$emne = "Ny tilmelding på UFL-ligevaerd.dk";
$besked = "<h1>Ny tilmelding</h1>
<p>Navn: " . $_POST['Navn']. "<br>"
. $_POST['Adresse'] . " " . $_POST['PostOgBy'] . "<br>
Fødselsdag: " . $_POST['Fodselsdag'] . "<br>
Telefonnummer: " . $_POST['Telefon'] . "<br>
Mail: " . $_POST['Mail'] . "<br>
Lokal UFL: " . $_POST['UFL-lokal'] . "<br>
Aktivt medlem: " . $akMedlem . "<br>
Støtte medlem: " . $stMedlem . "<br>
Skole medlem: " . $skMedlem;
$header = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$header .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$header .= "from: UFL-Ligevaerd.dk <ufl@ufl-ligevaerd.dk>;\r\n";

mail($modtager, $emne, $besked, $header);
$info = "Din tilmelding er sendt til UFL-Ligeværd";
$_POST = array();
}
}
?>
<form action="http://ufl-ligevaerd.dk/index.php/bliv-medlem" method="post">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Aktivt medlem (175kr.)</td>
<td><input name="akMedlem" type="checkbox" <?php if (isset($_POST['akMedlem'])) { echo 'checked="CHECKED"'; } ?> ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>St&oslash;ttemedlem(200kr.)</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="stMedlem" <?php if (isset($_POST['stMedlem'])) { echo 'checked="CHECKED"'; } ?>></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Skolemedlem(75kr. husk at skrive skolens navn)</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="skMedlem" <?php if (isset($_POST['skMedlem'])) { echo 'checked="CHECKED"'; } ?>></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Skolens navn</td>
<td><input type="text" name="sNavn" <?php if (isset($_POST['sNavn'])) { echo 'value="' . $_POST['sNavn'] . '"' ; } ?>></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>UFL-Lokalforening</td>
<td><input type="text" name="UFL-lokal" <?php if (isset($_POST['UFL-lokal'])) { echo 'value="' . $_POST['UFL-lokal'] . '"' ; } ?>></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Navn<sup>*</sup></td>
<td><input type="text" name="Navn" <?php if (isset($_POST['Navn'])) { echo 'value="' . $_POST['Navn'] . '"' ; } ?>></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Adresse<sup>*</sup></td>
<td><input type="text" name="Adresse"<?php if (isset($_POST['Adresse'])) { echo 'value="' . $_POST['Adresse'] . '"' ; } ?>></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Post.nr og by<sup>*</sup></td>
<td><input type="text" name="PostOgBy"<?php if (isset($_POST['PostOgBy'])) { echo 'value="' . $_POST['PostOgBy'] . '"' ; } ?>></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>F&oslash;dselsdag og &aring;r (dd-mm-yyyy)<sup>*</sup></td>
<td><input type="text" name="Fodselsdag" <?php if (isset($_POST['Fodselsdag'])) { echo 'value="' . $_POST['Fodselsdag'] . '"' ; } ?>></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Tlf<sup>*</sup></td>
<td><input type="text" name="Telefon" <?php if (isset($_POST['Telefon'])) { echo 'value="' . $_POST['Telefon'] . '"' ; } ?>></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Mail<sup></sup></td>
<td><input type="text" name="Mail" <?php if (isset($_POST['Mail'])) { echo 'value="' . $_POST['Mail'] . '"' ; } ?>></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><input type="hidden" name="sent" value="1" id="hiddenField">
<input type="submit" value="Send mail"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
<p><sup>*</sup>Kr&aelig;vet information</p>
<?php if (isset($info)) { echo "<p>Besked: ".$info."</p>"; } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: You want to send the email only when your all fields are filled else no email..isnt it ?

Comment: the required fields are Navn, Adresse, PostOgBy, Fodselsdag and Telefon.
But then i also want so if you use the check box skMedlem, then the field sNavn is required aswell.

the php is set so if the checkboxes is checked then it just says 'ja' otherwise its a 'nej'... and it all been working but isnt any more for some odd reason.

Comment: the action="http://ufl-ligevaerd.dk/index.php/bliv-medlem" is at the samme page as the form is on, ive been useing <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?> before, but it didnt work..... neither of the error messages are being printet when an error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is now working, but ive had to remove it from the joomla it self, and its now at a php sideby with an inframe.

Apperntly joomla 2.8 isnt too happy about the php